# QGIS with Qt 6.x

Tags: qgis, qt

When I build my project with Qt-Version 5.12.8, there is no problem and it works flawlessly. However, when I build it with Qt 6.2.2, I get the following error:

```
map.cpp:(.text.startup+0x683): undefined reference to `QgsSettingsEntryStringList::QgsSettingsEntryStringList(QString const&, QgsSettings::Section, QList<QString> const&, QString const&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not calling the method QgsSettingsEntryStringList::QgsSettingsEntryStringList() in map.cpp explicitly. I think the problem is with a header file, thus I need to update my QGIS folder. To which branch / commit should I change my local repo? Is QGIS compatible with Qt 6.2.2?

Comment: QGIS with Qt6 isn't yet available. Good news : the last grant program chose it's resolution, see the QGIS Enhancement Proposal : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/243

Comment: I think you should put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thank you for the answer.